# Latex does not work in Google Drive in Linux via gnome-online-accounts

Tags: path, google-drive-api, latex, linux-mint, texmaker

I installed google drive to Linux Mint 20 via gnome-control-accounts following instructions from here: https://www.fosslinux.com/1954/how-to-install-google-drive-on-linux-mint-18-1-18-2.htm

I have some Latex files in google drive. When I open them via gnome-control-accounts, the paths look very odd: instead of my original "myfile.tex" it is some abracadabra like this:

"/run/user/1000/gvfs/google-drive:host=gmail.com,user=myname/12ZSQjF4pmvwGE0bZzXwgxSrRS-lPD2ML".

When I open the file with TexMaker, it gives an error

Could not start the command.
pdfLatex-synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex

I believe this happens because of the odd path name under which my tex files are saved.

How to solve this?

Merci beaucoup.

P.S. I also installed google-drive via ocamlfuse following instructions from here:
https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-mount-your-google-drive-on-linux-with-google-drive-ocamlfuse/ .
It does run the latex files, but it works only in online mode, and you have to mount the disk manually each time you start your computer.

Answer (score 0):

try mounting google drive via google-drive-ocamlfuse

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).